# "Mathai-Quillen-type" form on $M\times M$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, euler-characteristics

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact, oriented, $(2n)$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.  I'm wondering whether there is a "canonical" construction of a $(2n)$-form $\eta_g$ on $M\times M$, such that

1. $\eta_g$ is a de Rham representative
   of the Poincare dual of the
   diagonal;
2. The pullback under the diagonal
   inclusion $\iota:M\to M\times M$
   is proportional to the curvature Pfaffian:
   $\iota^*\eta_g=\tfrac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\text{Pf}(\text{Rm})$.

There are plenty of "non-canonical" such forms, I think.  For instance, pick a neighbourhood of the diagonal which is diffeomorphic to $TM$, and transfer the Mathai-Quillen Thom form on $TM$ to this neighbourhood using a suitable diffeomorphism.  (By the way, the Mathai-Quillen Thom form on the total space of a bundle-with-metric-and-connection is the model I have in mind here for what "canonical" should mean -- a form whose value at each point depends only on local invariants.)

**Motivation:**  Such a form would yield a proof of the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem which is both quick and natural.  Namely,

$\chi(M)=PD(\Delta)\cup PD(\Delta)=\int_\Delta \eta_g =\tfrac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_M \text{Pf}(\text{Rm})$.

Answer (score 5):

I was styding the paper of [Jean Michael Bismut and Christophe SOULÉ, Complex Immersions and Arakelov Geometry](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~bismut/Bismut/1990k.pdf) 
The following answer may help

In the case when $M$ is a vector space or co-adjoint orbit via KKS symplectic form we know the answer

Take $\pi : T^*M\to M$ be a cotangent bundle and $s:M\to T^*M$ be as section then from the work of Bismut and Soule it is known that

$$s^*\mu_0(T^*M)=(2\pi)^{-m/2}\text{Pf}(D^2)$$

Here the Thom class $\mu_t(T^*M)=(-1)^{m(m-1)/2}(2\pi)^{-m/2}B(e^{-\omega_t})$ considered when $t\to 0$ and  $B\{·\}$ is the Berezin integral and $\omega_t=\frac{1}{2}t^2|x|^2+tDx+D^2$

Now in the special case when $M$ is a vector space then $T^*M\cong M\times M$ (and hence $s$ is just $\iota$). So when $M$ is the vector space this gives an answer to your question [see this paper](http://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~getzler/Papers/thom.pdf) and

also

If we change your question a little bit and if we Take $M=G$ as lie gorup and consider $T^*G\cong G\times T_eG\to G$ then we can find a relation between pull-back of Kirillov–Kostant—Souriau symplectic form on coadjoint orbit $\mathcal O_\mu$ and Mathai-Quillen form. In page 11 of [my Master expose in Marseille](https://fr.slideshare.net/HassanJolany/geometric-quantization-on-coadjoint-orbits), 2014 you can find the canonical construction of KKS form and Pfaffian and by pervious construction you can relative it to Mathai-Quillen form

and also the book of Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators by Berline, Nicole, Getzler, Ezra, Vergne, Michèle
http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540200628